# For each of the following languages, give a regular expression over {a, b}

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

$\{a^{2n}b^{n+k+1}a^k ∈ \{a, b\}^∗ \mid n \ge 0, k \ge 0\}$

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried.

Comment: This is unreadable. Use Matjax syntax.

Comment: My -1 for showing no effort, not even adapting the title of the exercise sheet.

Answer (score 0):

$L = \{ a^{2n} b^{n+k+1} a^k \mid n,k \ge 0\}$ is not a regular language.

Suppose towards a contradiction that $L$ is regular and let $p$ be its pumping length. Consider the word $b^{p} a^{p-1} \in L$. By the pumping lemma there is some positive integer $i \le p$ such that, for every $h \ge 0$:
$$b^{p-i} b^{hi} a^{p-1} \in L.$$
Choosing $h=0$ we obtain:
$$b^{p-i} a^{p-1} \in L,$$
which provides the sought contradiction.